How to resolve "User validation failed: email path 'email' is required" error in MongoDB with Mongoose?
I'm working on a user authentication system using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB with Mongoose. When trying to create a new user through a signup route, I'm encountering an error that says "User validation failed: email path 'email' is required". This error occurs despite the fact that I've included the email field in my user schema, and I'm providing the email during the signup process.
Here's the relevant code:
user.js (User schema)
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (value) => {
                const re =
                  /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i
                  return value.match(re);
            },
            message: 'Please, enter a valid email address',
        }
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user',
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;


auth.js (Signup route)
const express = require("express");
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.post("/api/signup", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ msg: 'User with same email already exists' });
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 8);

        let user = new User({
            email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            name,
        });
        user = await user.save();
        res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
    }
});

module.exports = authRouter;

I'm able to receive the name, email, and password from the client-side, but the user creation fails with the mentioned error. I've double-checked the user schema, and the email field is correctly defined as required and of type String.
Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this "User validation failed: email path 'email' is required" error and provide a solution to resolve it?

What's that "auth.js" code supposed to be? Because it's guaranteed not just what you put into your post. Also, what is the actual error? (e.g. show the error message including which file/line it occurred in, and the stack trace. As text, don't post a picture of the error)

Hello, I updated all my back end and when the errors triggered

I don't see the actual error though? Go to your dev tools, trigger the error, then copy and paste the entire error + stacktrace into your post.
